# What is the connection between the magnetization of a thermodynamic system, the magnetic fields, and the free energy?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, magnetic-fields

From multiple textbooks I gather

1. The first law of thermodynamics: $$dU = \delta Q + \delta W = TdS + \delta W$$
2. The definition of the free energy: $$F = U - TS \Rightarrow dF = -SdT + \delta W$$
3. The connection between the magnetization and the magnetic fields: $$\vec{B} = \vec{H} + 4\pi\vec{M}$$
4. The way authors like to "find" the magnetization of a thermodynamic system: $$\vec{M}(\vec{H}) = -\frac{1}{V}\frac{\partial U}{\partial\vec{H}} = -\frac{1}{V}\frac{\partial F}{\partial\vec{H}}$$

Can (4) be considered as the definition of the magnetization $\vec{M}$, and in turn (3) as the definition of the effective field $\vec{H}$ ? Or is (3) the definition of $\vec{H}$, and (4) can be derived from some electrostatic energy argument? In any case, what is the explicit form of $U(\vec{M})$ ? Is $U$ also a function of $\vec{B}$ or $\vec{H}$ ?

Comment: You might find Lungu's "Thermodynamics of Electric and Magnetic Systems" a useful resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start from the [Electrodynamic Lagrangian in matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism#Matter), which can be justified by the fact that one can derive Maxwell's equations from it.

It is fairly easy to see (harder to prove :-)) that the energy due to magnetization field will be (**ignoring constants**):

$$
U_B=\int_V d^3 r \mathbf{B}.\mathbf{M}=\int_V d^3 r \mathbf{H}.\mathbf{M}+\int_V d^3 r M^2
$$

The change in energy is therefore :

$$
\delta U_B=\int_V d^3 r \delta\mathbf{H}.\mathbf{M}+\int_V d^3 r \mathbf{H}.\delta \mathbf{M}+2\int_V d^3 r \mathbf{M}.\delta\mathbf{M}
$$

Imagine we are changing state of the system along the trajectory that keeps magnetization fixed (so $\delta \mathbf{M}=\mathbf{0}$), and that change $\delta\mathbf{H}$ is constant over volume $V$:

$$
\left(\frac{\partial U_b}{\partial \mathbf{H}}\right)_{\mathbf{M}}=\int_V d^3 r \mathbf{M}
$$

You can get rid of the integral if the magnetization is constant over volume $V$

Answer (score 0):

One can typically divide the state functions $\{\mathbf{X}\}$ into a set of generalized displacement $\{\mathbf{x}\}$, and their conjugate generalized forces $\{\mathbf{J}\}$, such that
$$\delta W=\sum_iJ_idx_i$$
In the case of Magnets, Force is a Magnetic field $J_i=B$ and displacement is magnetic dipole moment $m$.

In this respect, the first law of thermodynamics can be written as
$$dU=TdS-mdB$$
$$dF=-SdT-mdB$$
where $B=\mu_0(H+M)$.

---

There isn't any special definition for magnetization, It's the same all over. We can write magnetization as various partial derivatives using the above.
$$M=\frac{m}{V}=-\frac{1}{V}\left.\frac{\partial F}{\partial B}\right|_T$$

---

In general, there isn't any explicit expression for $U$. Any state function can be a function of any number of variables depending on system, but mostly two for fixed particles. From the first partial, You can take $U=U(S, B)$.